# How many cores can windows 2003 support?

Tags: windows, cpu, windows-server-2003, multi-processor

Windows 2003 DataCenter x64 supports up-to 64 physical processors.
[Support Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/888732)

Now what does this exactly mean ? Number of logical CPUs or the number of physical processors i.e. four intel i7s (Logical CPUs here will be 8x4=32)

And if its logical, what will happen if the windows is installed over more than 64 processors, will it not detect or will it detect but will be unable to use ?

Comment: This should mean number of sockets, irrespective of the cores. Windows will use up to the maximum of those populated sockets.

Comment: That means there is no limitation on the number of cores ?

Comment: There's always a theoretical maximum, but if you're talking Data Center Edition, it's academic anyway. Can you afford 64 x 10-core CPUs? And if you could, would you put them in one single chassis running one single OS? I know I wouldn't.

Comment: Suppose a scenario of 4 CPUs with 10 cores each with HyperThreading enabled, what would be the effect if using windows 2003 ? (4 x 10 x 2 Logical Cores)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [article you linked to](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/888732) already contains the answer you are asking for:

> x64-based versions of Windows Server 2003 that are running on a
>   computer that uses a multicore processor or a hyper-threading
>   processor support a maximum number of 64 logical processors.

As to your second question, I would guess that Windows 2003 will detect up to 64 physical processors and any number of logical processors, but will not use any logical processors above the maximum of 64.  In any case, I don't see that it makes much difference whether or not it detects the additional processors if it isn't going to use them anyway!

Comment: Alright, awesome. i don't know how did i miss that. Thankyou :)